# Python convert ddmmyy format to valid date

Tags: python, date-format

I was trying to convert a date string to a valid date python format, but I got a erroneous date:

```
>from datetime import datetime
>mydate = '300413' # is 2013-04-30
>print datetime.strptime(mydate,'%d%m%Y')
>0413-02-01 00:00:00
```

How can I parse to a valid date, this date string?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I vaguely remember this bug being fixed in the first bugfix after `datetime` was added (Tim Peters' bug reports on his own code always being memorable), and that's got to be… a decade ago or more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read [`strptime()` and `strftime()` Behavior](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) in the docs, `%Y` means:

> Year with century as a decimal number [0001,9999]

But you're giving it a 2-digit year, with *no* century.

That's supposed to raise a `ValueError`. For example, if you try it with 2.5.6, 2.7.2, 3.2.1, or 3.3.0, you get this:

> ValueError: time data '300413' does not match format '%d%m%Y'

But, thanks to a bug in older versions of Python, you might get garbage instead.

If you want a 2-digit year, use `%y`, when means:

> Year without century as a decimal number [00,99].

Answer (score 5):

As listed in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), `%Y` is the code for a four-digit year. You should be using the code for a two-digit year, `%y`.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
print datetime.strptime('300413','%d%m%y')
2013-04-30 00:00:00
```

only change `'%Y'` with `'%y'`